# how to get the value of multiple maximas in an array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array

```
a =[0,  0, 15, 17, 16, 17, 16, 12, 18, 18]
```

I am trying to find the element value that has `max` count. and if there is a tie, I would like all of the elements that have the same `max` count.

as you can see there are two 0, two 16, two 17,  two 18 one 15 and one 12
so i want something that would return 
`[0, 16, 17, 18]` (order not important but I do not want the 15 or the 12)

I was doing `np.argmax(np.bincount(a))` but `argmax` only returns one element (per its documentation) so I only get the 1st one which is 0

I tried 
`np.argpartition(values, -4)[-4:]` that works, but in practice I would not know that there are 4 elements that have the same count number! (maybe I am close here!!! the light bulb just went on !!!)

Comment: Have a look at `collections.Counter`, it counts stuff for you, then just have to find the max count and to retrieve all keys with that count.

Answer (score 8):

You can use  [np.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the counts and an array of the unique elements then pull the elements whose count is equal to the max:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 0, 15, 17, 16, 17, 16, 12, 18, 18])

un,  cnt = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)

print(un[cnt == cnt.max()])
[ 0 16 17 18]
```

un are the unique elements, cnt is the frequency/count of each:

```
In [11]: a = np.array([0, 0, 15, 17, 16, 17, 16, 12, 18, 18])

In [12]: un,  cnt = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)

In [13]: un, cnt
Out[13]: (array([ 0, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18]), array([2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]))
```

`cnt == cnt.max()` will give us the mask to pull the elements that are equal to the max:

```
In [14]: cnt == cnt.max()
Out[14]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Note that `return_counts=True` works on Numpy 1.9, for older versions you can use `np.bincount(a)[un]`

Comment: as suggested above worked with the Note by Kasramvd, for numpy older than 1.9 do import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 0, 15, 17, 16, 17, 16, 12, 18, 18])
un = np.unique(a)
cnt = np.bincount(a)[un]
print(un[cnt == cnt.max()])

Comment: @padraic Your solution will "only work" from Numpy 1.9, in older versions it throws error

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit fiddly but you can achieve this using `Counter` and `itemgetter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

a =[0, 0, 15, 17, 16, 17, 16, 12, 18, 18]
counter_list = Counter(a).most_common()
max_occurrences = max(counter_list, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
answer = [item[0] for item in counter_list if item[1] == max_occurrences]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 16, 17, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat solution:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 0, 15, 17, 16, 17, 16, 12, 18, 18])
freq_count = Counter(a)
high = max(freq_count.values())
res = [key for key in freq_count.keys() if freq_count[key]==high]
```

**Output: [0 16 17 18]**

Note: Output order not guaranteed